# Spring boot with querydsl problem with com.mysema.query.group.GroupBy

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, mysema

My Spring boot version :

```
<version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

and using query dsl like below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!--Plugin for query-dsl -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor </processor> 
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Everything is working with QTypes classes, but not able to import `com.mysema.query.group.GroupBy` to this class. Please help me for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining old and new versions of Querydsl.  Use

```
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1</version>
```

when using the newer `com.querydsl` artifacts.

Comment: I'm getting `Could not find goal 'process' in plugin com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.3.1`